# How to handle heavily nested objects with D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nested, visualization

Disclaimer: I'm very new to D3, so I'm certain this is possible but haven't yet figured out even what to search for to figure it out.

I'm trying to create a visualization using D3 that pulls from one large array full of nested JSON objects/arrays. For the sake of example, let's say my object looks like this:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "name":"John",
        "info":[
            {
                "age":31,
                "height":6,
                "weight":155,
                "eyes":"green"
            },
            {
                "age":35,
                "height":6,
                "weight":165,
                "eyes":"green"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Eric",
        "info":[
            {
                "age":29,
                "height":5,
                "weight":135,
                "eyes":"brown"
            },
            {
                "age":30,
                "height":5,
                "weight":155,
                "eyes":"brown"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, say I want to take this data and visualize it, but need to use more divs for styling than the nesting levels of the object reflect. So, I want code that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>John</h1>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>Age:31</h2>
                <div>
                    <p>Weight:155</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Age:35</h2>
                <div>
                    <p>Weight:165</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Eric</h1>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>Age:29</h2>
                <div>
                    <p>Weight:135</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Age:30</h2>
                <div>
                    <p>Weight:155</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, if I didn't have extra divs, it'd be fairly simple to use

```
var visualization = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(arr)
    .enter()
    .append("div");

var person = visualization.selectAll("h1")
    .data(function(d){return(d.name)}
    .enter()
    .append("h1")
    .text(function(d){return d});
```

And then I could do the same with divs and loop through d.info to create what I need. However, when I append nested divs I can no longer use the data of the parents to loop through, and can't seem to find the index of the parent div in the automatic looping through that .data() does.

Really, what I want to be able to do is create divs based on the length of arr[], append some info like "name" to that div, then append some divs for stylistic purposes to the root div, then get back into just the data of that root div for looping through. I would like to use D3 to do this because I know this is what it's built for, but at this point I'm about ready to brute force it using for loops where I know the index I'm in and can use that on more nested data. Hopefully that makes sense, but I'm completely stuck on how to properly do it using D3.

Please ask if any of this is unclear - really hoping to get this figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your issue.  Replicating your desired structure with that data isn't difficult.  You can append as many layers as you want and continue to access the parent data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    var arr = [{
      "name": "John",
      "info": [{
        "age": 31,
        "height": 6,
        "weight": 155,
        "eyes": "green"
      }, {
        "age": 35,
        "height": 6,
        "weight": 165,
        "eyes": "green"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Eric",
      "info": [{
        "age": 29,
        "height": 5,
        "weight": 135,
        "eyes": "brown"
      }, {
        "age": 30,
        "height": 5,
        "weight": 155,
        "eyes": "brown"
      }]
    }];

    var vis = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
      .data(arr)
      .enter()
      .append("div");
      
    vis.append("h1")
      .html((d) => d.name);
      
    var nestedDivs = vis.append("div").append("div");
    
    var innerDiv = nestedDivs.selectAll("div")
      .data((d) => d.info)
      .enter()
      .append("div");
      
    innerDiv.append("h2")
      .html((d) => "Age:" + d.age);
      
    innerDiv.append("div")
      .append("span")
      .html((d) => "Weight: " + d.weight);

  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```